# Group Every n Items in a Div with Mustache

Tags: javascript, html, css, mustache, templating

I need to format around 350 QR codes so that they can be printed in a template. I am able to generate the codes in the correct pattern however I have gotten stuck on the step of grouping them onto pages.

If possible how would I go about grouping every 30 items into a page.

This is what the current code returns (as you can see every 30nth child is marked):

[image]

This is a rough illustration of what I am trying to get to:

[image]

(p.s. I had to heavily cut off the json to fit in the charac. count :))

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}


.spacer {
    display: none;
}

.page {
    width: 8.5in;
    height: 11in;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;


}
.grid-container {
    margin-top: 1.125in;
    margin-bottom: 1.125in;
    margin-right: 0.625in;
    margin-left: 0.625in;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1.25in);
    grid-auto-rows: 1.25in;
    grid-gap: 0.25in;
    
}

.label {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1.9px solid black;
    width: 1.25in;
    height: 1.25in;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
}

.label:nth-child(30n){
    background-color: red;
}

.QR-Code {
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    width: 108%;
    height: auto;
}

.text-body {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Labels</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <div class="grid-container" id="labelCont">
            <script id="labelsTemplate" type="text-template">
                {{#labels}}
                    <div class="label">
                        <img class="QR-Code" src="/{{File}}">
                        <div class="text-body">{{Name}}</div>
                    </div>
                {{/labels}}
            </script>    
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/3.0.0/mustache.js"></script>
<script src="html2pdf.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var data = {
        "labels":[
            {
                "Name":"10000",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10000.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10001",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10001.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10002",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10002.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10003",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10003.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10004",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10004.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10005",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10005.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10006",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10006.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10007",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10007.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10008",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10008.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10009",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10009.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10010",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10010.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10011",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10011.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10012",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10012.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10013",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10013.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10014",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10014.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10015",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10015.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10016",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10016.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10017",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10017.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10018",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10018.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10019",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10019.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10020",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10020.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10021",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10021.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10022",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10022.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10023",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10023.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10024",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10024.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10025",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10025.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10026",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10026.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10027",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10027.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10028",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10028.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10029",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10029.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10030",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10030.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10031",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10031.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10032",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10032.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10033",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10033.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10034",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10034.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10035",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10035.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10036",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10036.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10037",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10037.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10038",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10038.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10039",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10039.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10040",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10040.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10041",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10041.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10042",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10042.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10043",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10043.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10044",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10044.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10045",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10045.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10046",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10046.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10047",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10047.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10048",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10048.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10049",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10049.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10050",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10050.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10051",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10051.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10052",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10052.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10053",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10053.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10054",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10054.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10055",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10055.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10056",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10056.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10057",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10057.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10058",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10058.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10059",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10059.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10060",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10060.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10061",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10061.png"
            }]
        }
        var template = $("#labelsTemplate").html();
        $("#labelCont").html(Mustache.to_html(template, data));
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `minmax()` value to set the row Height and then apply a hudge margin-bottom to each 30th element to push down next-row and show a visible break.

Here is an average idea to test on print preview to see if that spans correctly the grid into pages.*added a box-shadow to visualize the layout of cells after the break*

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}


.spacer {
    display: none;
}

.page {
    width: 8.5in;
    height: 11in;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 11in rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0 22in rgba(100,0,100,0.2), 0 33in rgba(100,50,0,0.2);


}
.grid-container {
    margin-top: 1.125in;
    margin-bottom: 1.125in;
    margin-right: 0.625in;
    margin-left: 0.625in;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1.25in);
    grid-auto-rows: min-max(1.25in, 2.5in);
    grid-gap: 0.25in;
    
}

.label {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1.9px solid black;
    width: 1.25in;
    height: 1.25in;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
}

.label:nth-child(30n){
    background-color: red;
    margin-bottom:190px;
}

.QR-Code {
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    width: 108%;
    height: auto;
}

.text-body {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Labels</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page">
        <div class="grid-container" id="labelCont">
            <script id="labelsTemplate" type="text-template">
                {{#labels}}
                    <div class="label">
                        <img class="QR-Code" src="/{{File}}">
                        <div class="text-body">{{Name}}</div>
                    </div>
                {{/labels}}
            </script>    
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/3.0.0/mustache.js"></script>
<script src="html2pdf.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var data = {
        "labels":[
            {
                "Name":"10000",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10000.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10001",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10001.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10002",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10002.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10003",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10003.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10004",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10004.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10005",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10005.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10006",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10006.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10007",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10007.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10008",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10008.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10009",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10009.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10010",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10010.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10011",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10011.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10012",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10012.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10013",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10013.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10014",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10014.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10015",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10015.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10016",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10016.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10017",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10017.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10018",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10018.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10019",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10019.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10020",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10020.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10021",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10021.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10022",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10022.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10023",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10023.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10024",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10024.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10025",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10025.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10026",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10026.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10027",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10027.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10028",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10028.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10029",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10029.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10030",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10030.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10031",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10031.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10032",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10032.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10033",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10033.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10034",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10034.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10035",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10035.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10036",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10036.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10037",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10037.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10038",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10038.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10039",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10039.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10040",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10040.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10041",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10041.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10042",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10042.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10043",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10043.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10044",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10044.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10045",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10045.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10046",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10046.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10047",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10047.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10048",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10048.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10049",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10049.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10050",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10050.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10051",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10051.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10052",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10052.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10053",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10053.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10054",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10054.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10055",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10055.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10056",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10056.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10057",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10057.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10058",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10058.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10059",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10059.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10060",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10060.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10061",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10061.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10001",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10001.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10002",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10002.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10003",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10003.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10004",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10004.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10005",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10005.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10006",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10006.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10007",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10007.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10008",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10008.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10009",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10009.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10010",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10010.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10011",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10011.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10012",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10012.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10013",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10013.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10014",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10014.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10015",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10015.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10016",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10016.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10017",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10017.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10018",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10018.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10019",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10019.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10020",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10020.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10021",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10021.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10022",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10022.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10023",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10023.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10024",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10024.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10025",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10025.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10026",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10026.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10027",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10027.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10028",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10028.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10029",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10029.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10030",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10030.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10031",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10031.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10032",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10032.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10033",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10033.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10034",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10034.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10035",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10035.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10036",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10036.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10037",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10037.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10038",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10038.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10039",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10039.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10040",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10040.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10041",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10041.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10042",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10042.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10043",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10043.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10044",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10044.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10045",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10045.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10046",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10046.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10047",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10047.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10048",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10048.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10049",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10049.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10050",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10050.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10051",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10051.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10052",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10052.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10053",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10053.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10054",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10054.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10055",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10055.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10056",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10056.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10057",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10057.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10058",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10058.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10059",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10059.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10060",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10060.png"
            },
            {
                "Name":"10061",
                "File":"QRCodes/QRCodePart_10061.png"
            }]
        }
        var template = $("#labelsTemplate").html();
        $("#labelCont").html(Mustache.to_html(template, data));
    });
</script>
</html>
```